# R combine data frame columns and transpose into new data frame

Tags: r

I have a series of data frames from which I wish to construct a new data frame in which each row represents one of the original data frames and the columns elements of the row data. i.e.:

```
data1 <- c("bill",1,"a","b")
data2 <- c("bob",2,"a","a")
data3 <- c("bert",3,"c","b")
data4 <- c("bill",1,"b","b")
data5 <- c("bob",2,"b","a")
data6 <- c("bert",3,"a","b")


file1 <- rbind(data1,data2,data3)
file2 <- rbind(data4,data5,data6)
```

whith this model data I would like a data frame such as this:

```
      bill    bob    bert
file1  a b    a a     c b
file2  b b    b a     a b
```

where each row represents a file and each column header is a row from these files "bill", "bob", "bert" etc. containing data from the 3rd and 4th columns of the files.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
z <- list(file1=file1,file2=file2)
res <- t(sapply(z, function(d) paste(d[,3],d[,4])))
colnames(res) <- file1[,1]

res
#        bill  bob   bert 
# file1 "a b" "a a" "c b"
# file2 "b b" "b a" "a b"
```

Comment: @akrun, Yeah, but it's hard-coded to columns 3 and 4. Your solution can deal with any number of columns.

Comment: Thank you, this works well for what I wanted and also transfers easily to more files.